# How to practice making self-signed certificates with intermediate CAs

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

I am trying to learn how ssl chain of trust works with practical examples.  I thought maybe `openssl` would be a good education tool.  But I'm running into a few problems while practicing, and I'm at a lost on how to approach my education.

Below is an experiment where I'm trying to set up certificates for a Root CA, Intermediate CA and an End User (I still don't have a confident understanding of what these terms mean despite several hours of googling and watching YouTube videos, hence my desire to experiment below).

I created and ran a bash script like this:

```
# make certs for root ca
openssl genrsa -out root.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -extensions v3_ca -key root.key -subj "/C=CA/ST=ON/O=HelloWorld/CN=root.example.com" -days 3650 -out root.crt

# make certs for intermediate ca
openssl genrsa -out intermediate.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -key intermediate.key -subj "/C=CA/ST=ON/O=HelloWorld/CN=intermediate.example.com" -out intermediate.csr
openssl x509 -req -extensions v3_ca -in intermediate.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out intermediate.crt -days 500 -sha256

# make certs for end user
openssl genrsa -out enduser.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -key enduser.key -subj "/C=CA/ST=ON/O=HelloWorld/CN=enduser.example.com" -out enduser.csr
openssl x509 -req -in enduser.csr -CA intermediate.crt -CAkey intermediate.key -CAcreateserial -out enduser.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

Then I tried to verify the `enduser.crt` along with the certificate chain.  But these commands all fail for various reasons:

```
>openssl verify -CAfile intermediate.crt enduser.crt
C = CA, ST = ON, O = HelloWorld, CN = intermediate.example.com
error 2 at 1 depth lookup: unable to get issuer certificate
error enduser.crt: verification failed

>openssl verify -CAfile <(cat intermediate.crt root.crt) enduser.crt
C = CA, ST = ON, O = HelloWorld, CN = intermediate.example.com
error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
error enduser.crt: verification failed

>openssl verify -CAfile <(cat root.crt intermediate.crt) enduser.crt
C = CA, ST = ON, O = HelloWorld, CN = intermediate.example.com
error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
error enduser.crt: verification failed
```

This command runs fine though

```
>openssl verify -CAfile root.crt intermediate.crt
intermediate.crt: OK
```

Have I completely misunderstood how intermediate CA work or how chain of trusts work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> openssl x509 -req -extensions v3_ca -in intermediate.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.key -CAcreateserial -out intermediate.crt -days 500 -sha256

With newer versions of openssl (3.0) you get here the warning:

> ```
> Warning: ignoring -extensions option without -extfile
> ```

While this warning is missing from older openssl versions (i.e. 1.1.1) it still ignores the argument. This will result in the intermediate.crt not having basic constraints CA:true and thus it is not usable as a CA certificate.

Once this is fixed by adding `-extfile /etc/ssl/openssl.conf` (or wherever your config is) these work fine:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile <(cat intermediate.crt root.crt) enduser.crt
enduser.crt: OK

$ openssl verify -CAfile <(cat root.crt intermediate.crt) enduser.crt
enduser.crt: OK
```

It is still failing to verify the enduser.crt solely by using the intermediate.crt though. This is because the intermediate certificate is not a self-signed root certificate, i.e. not the end of the trust chain. To treat such an intermediate certificate as acceptable end of trust chain one need to use the `-partial_chain` argument:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile intermediate.crt -partial_chain enduser.crt
enduser.crt: OK
```

Comment: Got it! So in the real world, an organization like Let's Encrypt will make `intermediate.*` and then lock away `root.key` securely somewhere. End users (like me) give Let's Encrypt `enduser.csr`.  Then Let's Encrypt will use `intermediate.crt` and `intermediate.key` to make `enduser.crt` and give me `enduser.crt` along with `root.crt` and `intermediate.crt`.  Is that the overall workflow?

Comment: @John: that's the basic idea, yes.